# How do I setup my routes to act like github's directory structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I would like to setup my directory structure like github has theirs:

website.com/user_name/project_name will be the projects#show action.

How can I do that using my routes file?

So website.com/user_name will be the projects#index action.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the route.

```
match ":username" => "projects#index"
match ":username/:project_name" => "projects#show"
```

Then, the controller.

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find_by_username!(params[:username])
    @projects = @user.projects
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username!(params[:username])
    @project = @user.projects.find_by_project_name!(params[:project_name])
  end
end
```

Simple as that!

Comment: Minor critique: In Rails 3 you can get away with just `projects#index` rather than `ProjectsController#index`.

Comment: thank you! what about when I use link_to...how do I call both of those links?

Comment: also, in the projectscontroller#index, I don't want to list the users but rather I want to list the projects by that user. Is that still the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Tnx Ryan, fixed. Matthew, yes, it is. You probaby want to say `@projects = @user.projects`. You need to fetch the user record in order to get the ID of the user since that's the foreign key in the projects table.